# Discord.JS List item values of ModelType are required

Tags: discord.js

I'm making a message content logging for my own server bot to logs all the message will be sent inside the server including embeds and pictures and gif but pics and gif when sending those (directly not by link) using upload files on discord it prompt this error:

**DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body
embeds[0][LIST_ITEM_VALUE_REQUIRED]: List item values of ModelType are required**

I'm using discord.js v14

This is my code

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { WebhookClient } = require('discord.js');
const client = require('../index');
const wbc = new WebhookClient({
    id: "",
    token: "",
});

module.exports = {
    name: 'messageCreate',
    async execute(message) {
        // if (message.channel.id === "999954713887907870") {
        if (message.channel.id === "1003856060647477298") return;
        let content = message.content ? message.content : { embeds: [message.embeds[0]] };

        wbc.send(content)
    }
    // }
}
```

If you want to see the whole error message you can click [here.](https://sourceb.in/SjyCQc4Ior)

Answer (score 1):

the error "List item values of ModelType are required" is an error meaning that the method is expecting items of a certain type (here it is expecting one or more embeds).

In your case, the error can occur for multiple reasons :
First, the user sends a file : In that case, there is *possibly* no text, so it takes the embeds, and there is no embeds neither, and the error occurs.
It also can occur if you don't have the messageContent intent enabled (on the discord developper portal, and in the code, so the content is always null (or undefined, I don't remember), and the bot automatically uses embeds, once again, they are unexisting.

What you can do to solve your problem is to check for these reasons, here is an example of solution :

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { WebhookClient } = require('discord.js');
const client = require('../index');
const wbc = new WebhookClient({
    id: "",
    token: "",
});

module.exports = {
    name: 'messageCreate',
    async execute(message) {
        // if (message.channel.id === "999954713887907870") {
        if (message.channel.id === "1003856060647477298") return;
        let content = message.content ? message.content : { embeds: [message.embeds[0]] };

        wbc.send({
            content: message.content,
            embeds: message.embeds
        });
    }
    // }
}
```

It is possible that this code doesn't work (because I didn't test it, sorry), in that case use this one (I'm sure this one will work)

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { WebhookClient } = require('discord.js');
const client = require('../index');
const wbc = new WebhookClient({
    id: "",
    token: "",
});

module.exports = {
    name: 'messageCreate',
    async execute(message) {
        // if (message.channel.id === "999954713887907870") {
        if (message.channel.id === "1003856060647477298") return;
        const content = { content: message.content, embeds: message.embeds };

        wbc.send(Object.keys(content).filter(x => ![null, undefined].includes(content[x]).map(x => content[x]).catch(() => {});
    }
    // }
}
```